# How to add a ResourceServer to an existing spring security config

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I use the following security configuration for authorization. I now want to add token secured endpoints to this project.

However, whenever I send a request to the secured endpoint I always find myself redirected to the login-page (*"/oauth_login"*) as if I were unauthorized.
What am I doing wrong here? I tried to debug this and it seems the overriden `decode()` function of my `accessTokenConverter` is never called when I try to access the endpoint with a valid token.

This is the security config I already have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@Order(1)
class SecurityConfig(
        private val userDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
        private val inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository: InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository,
        private val secretAuthenticationFilter: SecretAuthenticationFilter
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManager() = super.authenticationManager()

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder?) {
        auth!!.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder(10))
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        http.addFilterAfter(secretAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth_login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/accounts/password")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logoutconfirm")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/oauth_login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth_login")
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize-client")
                .authorizationRequestRepository(authorizationRequestRepository())
                .authorizationRequestResolver(CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorize-client"))
                .and()
                .tokenEndpoint()
                .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
                .and()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/loginSuccess")
                .failureUrl("/loginFailure")
                .addObjectPostProcessor(object : ObjectPostProcessor<Any> {
                    override fun <O : Any> postProcess(obj: O) = when (obj) {
                        is OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider -> CustomOAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider(obj) as O
                        is LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint -> customizeLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(obj) as O
                        else -> obj
                    }
                })

    }
```

This is the ResourceServerConfig I want to add:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(2)
class ResourceServerConfig(
        private val defaultTokenServices: DefaultTokenServices
) : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(config: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices())
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()

    }

    fun tokenStore() = JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter())

    fun accessTokenConverter(): JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        val converter = object : JwtAccessTokenConverter() {
            override fun decode(token: String) = if (token.isCorrectJwtToken(token)) {
                super.decode(token)
            } else {
                mapOf()
            }
        }

        val keyStoreKeyFactory = KeyStoreKeyFactory(ClassPathResource("mykeys.jks"),
                "mykeys".toCharArray())
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("mykeys"))
        return converter
    }

    fun tokenServices() = DefaultTokenServices().apply {
        setTokenStore(tokenStore())
        setSupportRefreshToken(true)
    }
```

This is the secured endpoint I want to be able to access with a valid token:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @PostMapping("/accounts/password")
    fun updatePassword(@RequestBody newPassword: JsonWrappedValue<String>): Boolean {
        // Update password
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
I merged all configs into a single file so the security config looks like that

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@PropertySource("application.properties")
class SecurityConfig(
        private val accountRepository: AccountRepository,
        private val userDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
        private val inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository: InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository,
        private val secretAuthenticationFilter: SecretAuthenticationFilter
) : AuthorizationServerConfigurer, ResourceServerConfigurer, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter()
```

This made me able to finally reach my endpoint with a token but destroyed my social login.
Then I had to fix the `configure(http: HttpSecurity)` method as the ResourceServerConfig's default implementation sets the `SessionCreationPolicy` to `SessionCreationPolicy.Never`.

This caused my social login to get destroyed because the request parameters containing redirectUri and so on could not be restored. After adding

```
http.sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
```

to `configure(http: HTTPSecurity)` the complete configuration works well.